# Вопрос с фиксацией ширины .logo

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при расширении nav-а ширина `.logo` была фиксированная = `174px`.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(64, 145, 165);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 100px rgb(48, 116, 156);
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.logo {
  width: 172px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: А сейчас что не так?